# Ignore 'Security Warning' running script from command line

Tags: security, powershell

I am trying to execute a script from shared folder that I trust:

```
PowerShell -file "\\server\scripts\my.ps1"
```

But I get a security warning, and have to press 'R' to continue

> Security Warning Run only scripts that
>   you trust. While scripts from the
>   Internet can be useful, this script
>   can potentially harm your computer. Do
>   you want  to run
>   \server\scripts\my.ps1? [D] Do not
>   run  [R] Run once  [S] Suspend  [?]
>   Help (default is "D"): d

Can I ignore this warning? The desired pseudo code I want is:

```
PowerShell -IGNORE_SECURITY_WARNING -file "\\server\scripts\my.ps1"
```

Answer (score 95, accepted):

This is touched in ["PowerShell Execution Policies in Standard Images" on Lee Holmes' Blog](http://www.leeholmes.com/blog/2008/07/24/powershell-execution-policies-in-standard-images/) and ["PowerShell’s Security Guiding Principles" on the *Windows Power Shell Blog*](http://blogs.msdn.com/powershell/archive/2008/09/30/powershell-s-security-guiding-principles.aspx)
.

**Summary**
Some machines treat UNC paths as the big bad internet, so PowerShell treats them as remote files. You can either disable this feature on those servers (`UncAsIntranet = 0,`) or add the remote machines to your trusted hosts.

If you want to do neither, PowerShell v2 supports an `-ExecutionPolicy` parameter that does exactly what your pseudocode wants. `PowerShell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File (...)`.

Comment: Thank you! -ExecutionPolicy Bypass is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @LeeHomes I was looking for something else but `-ExecutionPolicy ByPass` fixed my problem. You saved me lot of googling and time. Thanks

Comment: Just to clarify - "add to trusted hosts" means in the system's internet options, available via control panel or in internet explorer.  The name appears to be a string match.  my share name is `\\foo-files`.  Adding the name `foo-files.example.com` to trusted hosts did not work, i had to just add the name `foo-files`.

Comment: Re: `-ExecutionPolicy` This command only whitelists the script for the instance in which it's being run, offering no help to those running scripts usign the "Run" button in PowerShell ISE.  Is there a way to globally trust this file that 1. Is persistent -- and -- 2. Doesn't involved executing the script.

Futher caution... Changing the Local Intranet zone and/or Trusted Zones on a domain can have unintended side-effects on websites which rely on specific browser features to work.  For example, ActiveX, http and ws traffic can be unobviously blocked depending on the origin vs. zone.

Comment: where do I put this UncAsIntranet?

Answer (score 54):

To avoid warnings, you can:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy bypass
```

Comment: Warning: This sets ExecutionPolicy on the entire machine, which is a big security risk.  @LeeHolmes solution up above sets ExecutionPolicy just for that session, which is a lower risk.

Comment: I find the security implications to be atrocious however this is the only way I've found to edit a remote file with PowerShell ISE and not have a popup each time the run button is clicked... at least without changing Internet Security settings which -- in the case of the target environment -- would break ActiveX content as well as some poorly-chosen-but-needed cross-domain security settings that only work in the default Local Intranet Zone.

Answer (score 51):

If you're running into this error from a downloaded powershell script, you can unblock the script this way:

1. Right-click on the `.ps1` file in question, and select **Properties**
2. Click **Unblock** in the file properties

   [image]
3. Click **OK**

Comment: Thanks!! This worked for me, i was being prompted every launch even with Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted

Comment: At least on my machine, `Unblock-File` does not seem to help with a UNC path as illustrated in the original question nor does the `Unblock` button appear in the file's property dialog.  I assume this is because your file is hosted locally `C:\...`, which makes this answer invalid to the original question (albeit helpful to >=28 others)

Comment: Definitely helped for me.  Due to limitations in our environment we had to install modules manually (https://stackoverflow.com/a/37488195/74276) then install them on the server (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/module/installing-a-powershell-module?view=powershell-7).  Then we found that we had to run "Get-ChildItem | Unblock-File" to unblock all files in the module folder (under the version number folder).

Answer (score 17):

Just assign 1 to SEE_MASK_NOZONECHECKS env variable

```
$env:SEE_MASK_NOZONECHECKS = 1
Start-Process $msi_file_path /qn -Wait | out-null
```

Comment: `Start-Process` doesn't support `-ExecutionPolicy Bypass` so it was failing on an UNC path, even with UAC disabled. But with this trick it works. Upvoting with all my hands.

Comment: You sir win the night.

Comment: You made my day, seriously this guy deserves a pay raise

Answer (score 4):

Try this, edit the file with:

```
notepad foo.ps1:Zone.Identifier
```

And set 'ZoneId=0'

Comment: Or, in V3, `Unblock-File` (though this comment and this answer both have nothing to do with the IO's question)

Comment: For some reason, I couldn't see `Unblock-File` even with v4, but the Zone.Identifier workaround did the thing. The file was also created on the host, but still the prompt with the system execution policy 'RemoteSigned'.

Answer (score 4):

I made this powershell script to unblock all files on a share on my server

```
Get-ChildItem "\\ServerName\e$\MyDirectory\" -Recurse -File | % {
       Unblock-File -Path $_.FullName
}
```

Comment: `Unblock-File` did not work in my tests (Windows 10, PowerShell ISE).

Answer (score 3):

None of this worked in my specific instance.  What did was changing to a NetBIOS name from the FQDN.

Instead of:
    `\\server.domain.net\file.ps1`
use:
`\\server\file.ps1`

Using the name bypasses the "automatically detect intranet network" config in IE.

See Option 1 in the blog here:
http://setspn.blogspot.com/2011/05/running-powershell-scripts-from-unc.html

Answer (score 2):

You want to set the execution policy on your machine using Set-ExecutionPolicy:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
```

You may want to investigate the various execution policies to see which one is right for you. Take a look at the "`help about_signing`" for more information.

Comment: That will change the execution policy permanently, which may nor be desired for a one-off use.

Comment: setting ExecutionPolicy to Unrestricted allows network script execution, but does not bypass the prompt.

Comment: You want to use "bypass" instead of "unrestricted". "Bypass" is even LESS restrictive than "unrestricted" and gets rid of the security prompting.

Answer (score 1):

Did you download the script from internet?

Then remove NTFS stream from the file using sysinternal's [streams.exe](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897440.aspx) on command line.

```
cmd> streams.exe .\my.ps1
```

Now try to run the script again.

Comment: Or, in V3, `Unblock-File` (though this comment and this answer both have nothing to do with the IO's question)

Answer (score 0):

Assume that you need to launch ps script from shared folder

```
copy \\\server\script.ps1 c:\tmp.ps1 /y && PowerShell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File c:\tmp.ps1 && del /f c:\tmp.ps1
```

P.S.
Reduce googling)

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple to do, open your PowerShell and write the following command if you have number of ps1 files. here you have to change the path with your path.

```
PS C:\Users> Get-ChildItem -Path "D:\downlod" -Recurse | Unblock-File
```

Comment: no. The files are not blocked and I still get prompts when I run it from \\tsclient\h via ISE

Answer (score 0):

Try set-executionpolicy  "Policyname" -force switch and the warnings pop-up should not come.

Answer (score 0):

For those who want to access a file from an already loaded PowerShell session, either use [Unblock-File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/unblock-file?view=powershell-7) to mark the file as safe (though you already need to have set a relaxed execution policy like `Unrestricted` for this to work), or change the execution policy just for the current PowerShell session:

```cs
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process
```

Answer (score 0):

For my part, I was running my script by a command, and was accessing it by an alias name. Just changing the alias by the real path ("\\ServerName\" -> "C:\") in my command worked for me, since it is considered local, and so safe

Comment: Please use code blocks to make this more readable