# Powershell script - suppress security popup

Tags: powershell, file-permissions

I downloaded PS script from http://poshcode.org/2216. Whenever I  try to run this script, security popup appears: "Run only scripts that you trust. While Scripts from the internet can be usefull, this script can potentially harm your computer. If you trust this script, use the Unblock-File cmdlet to allow the script to run without this warning message. (...)".

So I executed `Unblock-File .\Send-File.ps1` but nothing changed. I also tried other variations like `Get-Content .\SendFile | Unblock-File`. Nothing seems to work.

Does anyone know what is the proper way to unblock PowerShell script? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you check this out? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/728143/ignore-security-warning-running-script-from-command-line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also wipe the ZoneId from the alternate data stream :

```
set-Content Send-File.ps1 -Stream zone.identifier -Value ''
```

Comment: It seems like it should work, but after calling it result is the same.

Comment: what is the result of `get-Content Send-File.ps1 -Stream zone.identifier`

Comment: It appears after PC restart your solution did the job.

Answer (score 1):

To unblock a particular script file, Sam's answer will be ok.
You also can run a script without actually unblocking it by bypassing your PowerShell execution policy explicitly.
To do that execute the following console command:

`powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass .\Send-File.ps1`

... and the script will start

Answer (score 0):

Right-click the downloaded script, select properties and unblock.

Answer (score 0):

By default the downloaded PS script will be treated as unsafe. You need to set Powershell's execution policy to bypass the security check for this particular file.

To do that, execute:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File (...)
```

(Note that it is possible to run the above command with no File specified, which globally sets the execution policy to bypass the security check; we do not recommend you do that!)

Comment: In PS versions i checked there is no `File` parameter for `Set-ExecutionPolicy` cmdlet. I am using v4.0.