# how to install a Powershell module in Powershell 4?

Tags: sql-server, powershell, powershell-4.0, powershell-module, dbatools

I have some machines on [Powershell 4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1825807/1501497)

[image]

In these machines even after I have placed the new powershell modules within the module path
they don't show  up in the  `Modules` drop down list - as above.

when I do the same thing in machines that are on Powershell 5 I can see the new modules in the `Modules` drop down list as below.

[image]

what else I have to do in order to make the new modules show up in the `modules` drop down on Powershell 4?

Comment: PowerShell 6.0 was released in Jan 2018 and end-of-life in Feb 2019. Perhaps it's time to upgrade to a more modern version of PowerShell than 4.0 and 5.0?

Comment: it is very kind of you to remind me of this undisputed fact, however, other than upgrading, anything else you can think of in order for the modules to start showing in the drop down list?

Comment: I have been looking at [upgrading to powershell 7](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-core-on-windows?WT.mc_id=THOMASMAURER-blog-thmaure&view=powershell-7)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Install-Module : The term 'Install-Module' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41585758/2029983)

Comment: Do they just not _show in the GUI_ or are they also _not available_ in the session?

Comment: Since you're thinking about upgrading to PowerShell 7, let me add some info on the future of the Windows PowerShell ISE:

Comment: The PowerShell ISE is [no longer actively developed](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/components/ise/introducing-the-windows-powershell-ise#support) and [there are reasons not to use it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57134096/45375) (bottom section), notably not being able to run PowerShell [Core] 6+. The actively developed editor that offers the best PowerShell development experience, across platforms, is [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/), combined with its [PowerShell extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.PowerShell).

Comment: @mklement0 thank you for the links - exactly what I needed, I was already looking for a ISE for PowerShell 7, I am glad and thankful that you posted these links

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41585758/1501497) provided by [Larnu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2029983/larnu) in the comments

After I found the powershell module file `.psm1` and run the following command:

```
import-Module  "C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\dbatools\1.0.141\dbatools.psm1"
```

[image]