# How does Import-Module works for PSM1 file in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, import-module

I know how to import modules in PowerShell. I have already gone through [Import-Module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/import-module?view=powershell-7.1).

I want to know how import-module works behind the scene. Thoughts?

Comment: If you're really interested, you could always [read the source](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/Modules/ImportModuleCommand.cs). (Technically this is only for PowerShell 6+, earlier versions were proprietary, although you could still reverse engineer the code with a decompiler.) There is little reason to do so if you're not an active PowerShell developer and/or diagnosing a bug, though.

Comment: Kindly refer my answer where I have covered [This Part](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41585758/install-module-the-term-install-module-is-not-recognized-as-the-name-of-a-cm/41586317#41586317)