# How to install/update a powershell module from a local folder - set up an internal module repository

Tags: powershell, powershellget

I need to install a PowerShell module (i.e. sqlserver) on one production box, however, the production server does not have any internet connection.

An alternative way I am using is to use save-module to save module files onto a shared folder and then copy the files from the shared folder directly to production server's PS module path

```
c:\program files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules
```

It works, but I am just wondering whether we can use the existing approach, i.e. install-module, something like

```
install-module -name sqlserver -repository "my shared folder"
```

This requirement extends to update-module as well.

Using save-module and then copy & paste seems very unreliable because I have no idea whether install-module will actually do some DLL file registration or installation.

Can any PS gurus please give some idea how to do this, i.e. using install-module without internet connection?

Thanks in advance for your time.

PS: I know there is a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41122113/install-powershell-module-in-closed-network) at SO but it does not help me.

Comment: https://kevinmarquette.github.io/2017-05-30-Powershell-your-first-PSScript-repository/

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler, it seems very promising after 1st scan. I will try it later. On the otherhand, can you please write something in the answer section instead of comment so I can vote you up. Thanks again !

Answer (score 19):

1. In any shell (elevated or not):

   ```
    Register-PSRepository -Name 'myRepositoryName' -SourceLocation 'C:\MyExampleFolder'
   ```

   All `.nupkg` files inside your folder are now discoverable by `Install-Module`.
2. In an elevated shell (Run as Administrator):

   ```
    Install-Module 'Some-Module' -Repository 'myRepositoryName'
   ```

Comment: It will work, however `SourceLocation` needs to be at least network share - it was not working for me when I've used local path.

Comment: @Gucu112 Not true, you can definitely use a local path. What error message were you getting?

Comment: The diff between **install-module** and **import-module** seems that **import-module** can only install from a local path whereas **install-module** can install from local and from remote.

Comment: @Timo Not exactly. `Import-Module` makes a module's cmdlets accessible to you in your *current PowerShell session*. `Install-Module` *copies a module's files to a location*. Importing is like putting food on your counter to make a sandwich, whereas installing is like going shopping and bringing the food home from the store.

Comment: Worked for me here! My server lacks internet access, downloaded manually the nupkg file PowerShell Galley and put into a folder "C:\Temp", registered the PSRepository with "C:\Temp" as SourceLocation and installed the module. Many thanks!!

Answer (score 4):

Eric's answer was helpful for me.  I also added:

```
-InstallationPolicy Trusted
```

to the `Register-PSRepository` call.
Taking a module and publishing it as a nuget package looks like this:
`Publish-Module -Name myModuleName -Repository myRepositoryName`