# Run a signed powershell script from the command line without having to confirm that I want to run it?

Tags: windows, powershell, command-line, group-policy, executionpolicy

I am trying to run a signed PS script from a cmd window using this command:

```
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy bypass -File \\server01.company.local\emp\TestParams2.ps1 myserver "\\server1\folder name\file.txt" 9999
```

When I do, I get this:

```
[D] Do not run  [R] Run once  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "D"):
```

I signed the script and it is not blocked.  AND I can run it from other servers  in the same zone and subject to the same group policies, logged in as the same user, without having this confirmation request come up.  I must have a setting that is specific to this machine that is blocking it, but I can't figure it out.  These are the current execution policies:

```
powershell Get-executionpolicy -list

        Scope ExecutionPolicy
        ----- ---------------
MachinePolicy    Unrestricted
   UserPolicy    Unrestricted
      Process       Undefined
  CurrentUser          Bypass
 LocalMachine          Bypass
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I guess that is because your script is remote and not in a trusted zone (internet zone setting) try to run the script from a local drive or using the netbios name: `\\server01\emp\TestParams2.ps1`

Comment: @iRon, it does run locally.  Do you know where I could look to find out the differences between the zone for this server and for the server that it does work on?

Comment: Your result is expected, because your machine and user policy are set to `Unrestricted` rather than `Bypass`. See `help about_Execution_Policies`.

Comment: Apart from what what @Bill_Stewart commented, your (trusted) zone settings are defined in your internet settings.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ignore 'Security Warning' running script from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728143/ignore-security-warning-running-script-from-command-line)